# Confusion in Total faces in Cone: 3D

Tags: geometry, 3d

I have checked in many places about how many faces does a Cone have..

**[As per this link. There is 1 face in Cone](http://www.11plusforparents.co.uk/Maths/shape8.html)**

**[As per this link, there are 2 faces in cone](http://www.math-only-math.com/geometrical-shapes.html)**

**[As per this Video, A Cone has one face only](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0ahUKEwiqipna-cLMAhUUwI4KHawfBdgQtwIIMjAH&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DBPrVAT_x1f4&usg=AFQjCNEBmo_enTBzPvtETbKPJLNSjTZtqg&bvm=bv.121099550,d.c2E&cad=rja)**

I am assuming that like in sphere, there is one face only. In the same way, a Cone has 2 faces.

1. Base. which is circular face.
2. Curved surface as shown in the image below.

[image]

Can you give your valuable feedback about my understanding?

Comment: The first link says $2$ faces too (read again). The third link says $1$ $flat$ face.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : What's the correct answer?

Comment: Obvioulsy, all three answers are correct.

Comment: Does it means that a cone has two faces? 1 circular face and one curved face?

Comment: Is there any doubt about this ?

Comment: The first thing to do is write down your definition of "face".  It is a standard definition for a polyhedron.  But to apply it to something else (like a cone) you will need to write it down carefully!  Different definitions may provide different answers to the question "how many faces are in a cone?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether an open cone or close cone.  An open cone doesn't include the circular base while a close cone includes.

By the way, a close cylinder should include two circular bases and one curved surface.  You may have a semi-open cylinder (e.g. cylindrical pencil stand) which has one base.  The core of a toilet paper roll has two ends open,  that is one curved surface only.

**P.S.:**
In calculus texts, a cone is approached by a polygonal pyramid.  So a curved surface has infinitely many **"faces"** (that means tiny planes).

In differential geometry or topology, sphere and torus have inner and outer surfaces while [Klein bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle) is one-sided.

Comment: I selected your answer because of this sentence "It depends whether an open cone or close cone."

Answer (score 0):

A cone has a flat circular face as its base, and a curved surface seen as its curved face connecting the base boundary to a single point apex... There are two surfaces and an edge connecting them.

The curved cone surface is the sum of an infinite number of flat triangular faces.